# Como solucionar o erro "Array to string conversion" Laravel

Tags: php, json, array, laravel

Estou tentando atualizar um modal de formulário de cadastro. Está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

> Array to string conversion (SQL: update `checklist_protocolo` set `item` = 0, `item_descricao_id` = 5, `sim_nao` = on, `nao_atende` = on, `dt_validade` = 2019-04-29, `pagina_documento` = 1, `observacao` = Anotação where `projeto_id` = 4)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue trecho do código de atualização:

```
$projeto = $request->projeto_id;
$dados = $request->only(['item', 'item_descricao_id', 'sim_nao', 
                         'nao_atende', 'dt_validade', 
                         'pagina_documento', 'observacao']);                               
$checklistsProtocolos = checklistProtocolo::where('projeto_id', $projeto)
->update([
          'item' => $dados['item'],
          'item_descricao_id' => $dados['item_descricao_id'],
          'sim_nao' => $dados['sim_nao'],
          'nao_atende' => $dados['nao_atende'],
          'dt_validade' => $dados['dt_validade'],
          'pagina_documento' => $dados['pagina_documento'],
          'observacao' => $dados['observacao'] ]);
```

Qual é melhor forma para atualizar esses dados no erro mencionado?

Segue a tabela com seus respectivos tipos:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Formulário de cadastro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
array(9) { ["projeto_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["modelo_id"]=> string(1) "6" ["item"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "2" [3]=> string(1) "3" [4]=> string(1) "4" } ["item_descricao_id"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(1) "6" [2]=> string(1) "7" [3]=> string(1) "8" [4]=> string(1) "9" } ["sim_nao"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "on" [1]=> string(2) "on" [2]=> string(2) "on" } ["dt_validade"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(10) "2019-04-30" [1]=> string(10) "2019-04-30" [2]=> string(10) "2019-04-30" [3]=> string(10) "2019-04-30" [4]=> string(10) "2019-04-30" } ["pagina_documento"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(1) "1" } ["observacao"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(10) "Anotação" [1]=> string(10) "Anotação" [2]=> string(10) "Anotação" [3]=> string(10) "Anotação" [4]=> string(10) "Anotação" } ["nao_atende"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "on" [1]=> string(2) "on" } }
```

Código html:

```
 <!--Inicio do modal de Checklist do Projeto-->
```

```
              {{ csrf_field() }}
```

```
            <div class="modal-dialog2 modal-center">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Checklists do Protocolo</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                         <input type="hidden" id="projeto_id" name="projeto_id" value="{{$projeto->id}}">
                         <input type="hidden" id="modelo_id"  name="modelo_id" value="{{$modeloProtocolo[0]['id']}}">
                         <label class="control-label">Modelo</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="modeloProcesso" value="{{$modeloProtocolo[0]['modelo']}}" disabled> 

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-18">

                         <table id="checklistProtocolo" name="checklistProtocolo" class="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive toggle-arrow-tiny" >
                            <caption></caption>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Item</th> 
                                        <th>Descrição</th>
                                        <th>Sim/Não</th>
                                        <th>Não Atende</th>
                                        <th>Data de Validade</th>
                                        <th>Página do Documento</th>
                                        <th><center>Observações</center> </th>
                                        <th class="text-center"></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="bodyChecklists">

                                @foreach($checklistsProtocolos as $checklistProtocolo)

                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"  id="item" name="item[]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->item}}"  size ="2"></td>
                                    <td>{{$checklistProtocolo->descricao_item}}</td>   
                                    <input type="hidden"          id="item_descricao_id"  name="item_descricao_id[]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->item_descricao_id}}">
                                    <td><input type="checkbox"    id="sim_nao"            name="sim_nao[]"    {{$checklistProtocolo->sim_nao == null ? '' : 'checked'}}></td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox"    id="nao_atende"         name="nao_atende[]" {{$checklistProtocolo->nao_atende == null ? '' : 'checked'}}></td>
                                    <td><input type="date"        id="dt_validade"        name="dt_validade[]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->dt_validade}}"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text"        id="pagina_documento"   name="pagina_documento[]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->pagina_documento}}" size ="1"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text"        id="observacao"         name="observacao[]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->observacao}}" size ="1" style="width: 300px; height: 60px"></td>
                                </tr>

                                @endforeach 

                           </tbody>
                    </table>                              


                    </div>

                    </div><!--Fim do modal-body-->
```

Impressão dos dados sem tratamento de campos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: poderia passar essa tabela e seus tipos.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic  a descrição foi atualizada.

Comment: viu aqui oh: `nao_atende = on` esse é um campo com apenas 1 caracter ??? entendeu o problema

Comment: Se demora pra interagir a pergunta fica como não compreendida

Comment: Atualizei a descrição. Vale salientar que eu preciso salvar uma array de dados. E a mensagem de erro persistente só mostra atualização somente de uma linha.

Comment: dá um comando `var_dump` assim `var_dump($dados)`, porque o que você está enviando é um array de informações ... e cola na pergunta

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Atualizei a descrição com o print tela.

Comment: Vamos lá se viu que é um lista de valores, e por isso os campos `sim_nao` e `nao_atende` não tem a mesma quantidade de itens que os outros, porque eles são checkbox e o PHP não recupera aqueles que não forma marcados? Se conseguiu reparar isso.? como está seu HTML?

Comment: Sim. A grande questão é,  sem o tratamento desses campos (sim_não ou nao_atende no controller  mostrará os valores "on" conforme na descrição. Inserir o html na descrição.

Comment: A questão é pior ainda, aqueles que não forem selecionados não aparecem, tipo se você selecionou o último ele mostra como primeiro e falta 5 checkbox para saber se foi ou não selecionado! o correto ai é com select! Só para ratificar eu sei como resolver e não é assim! com checkbox  fica complicado solucionar

Comment: Não vão aparecer pq utilizei a sugestão, porém sem aquele tratamento dos campos a impressão dos dados irá aparecer assim: sim_nao = "on" ou não_atende = "on" dependendo da marcação do checkbox.

Comment: é uma sequencia de valores a primeira linha se você não marcar exemplo `sim_nao` como não vem nada você perde esse valor , e ai que é o problema você seleciona na segunda linha e ai o valor era como se fosse a primeira linha ... entendeu meu caro?

Comment: faz o seguinte como teste, troque checkbox por um select com dois options e ai entenderá o que estou falando

Comment: Eu entendi o que você disse só relatei o que está acontecendo com o campo. Farei o teste sugerido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução aplicada foi criar uma variável ($cont) para contar linha de cada array dentro do loop de repetição no método cadastroChecklistProtocolo.

Referência: [Salvar itens de um formulário checklist no banco - Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/382561/salvar-itens-de-um-formul%C3%A1rio-checklist-no-banco-laravel)

Segue código:

```
$cont = 0; //contador de linhas para os arrays

              for($i = 0; $i < count($dt_validade); $i++){

                   $dataInsert = array(
                         'sim_nao' => $sim_nao[$cont],                   
                         'dt_validade'=> $dt_validade[$cont], 
                         'pagina_documento' =>$pagina_documento[$cont], 
                         'observacao' =>$observacao[$cont]);           

                         $checklistsProtocolos = checklistProtocolo::where('projeto_id', $projeto_id)
                         ->whereIn('item_descricao_id', (array)$item_descricao_id[$cont])  //atualiza linha por linha do array
                         ->update($dataInsert);
                         $cont++; //atualiza linha por linha do array
                  }
```